# Round borders aren't clipping/masking perfectly

Tags: ios, border, calayer, clip

I make a label in Interface Builder, with constraints for fixed height and fixed width:
[image]

I subclass it to give it a white round border:

```
class CircularLabel: UILabel {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 5
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

But the clipping/masking isn't good at runtime:
[image]

I was expecting a perfect white border, without orange pixels.

iPhone 8 (Simulator and real device), iOS 11.2, Xcode 9.2, Swift 3.2

**MCVE at https://github.com/Coeur/stackoverflow48658502**

Comment: Can you give me this image so that i can try some efforts on it.

Comment: @dahiya_boy there is no image at all, but I added an MCVE on GitHub that you can clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved.

#### Nice solution

Add a 1 pixel stroke and `masksToBounds` will do the job for clipping the edges correctly:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    // workaround incomplete borders: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48663935/1033581
    UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!).setStroke()
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: layer.cornerRadius)
    path.lineWidth = 1
    path.stroke()
}
```

#### Explanations

Actually, from my tests, setting `layer.borderWidth = 5` is equivalent to formula:

```
let borderWidth: CGFloat = 5
UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!).setStroke()
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: borderWidth / 2, dy: borderWidth / 2),
                        cornerRadius: layer.cornerRadius - borderWidth / 2)
path.lineWidth = borderWidth
path.stroke()
```

But on the other hand `layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2` + `layer.masksToBounds = true` is going to clip with a different unknown method that has a different aliasing formula on the edges. Because the clipping and the drawing don't have the same aliasing, there are some pixels displaying the background color instead of the border color.

Answer (score 1):

You should use UIBezierPath to round corners and draw border line with same path. 
I my case i created CAShapeLayer with all adjustments and added it as sublayer to view.

---

```
let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: *get your view bounds*, cornerRadius: *needed radius*).cgPath

//Set this rounding path to both layers
shapeLayer.path = path
borderLayer.path = path

//adjust border layer
borderLayer.lineWidth = *border width*
borderLayer.strokeColor = *cgColor of your border*

//apply shape layer as mask to your view, it will cut your view by the corners
*yourViewInstance*.layer.mask = shapeLayer

//Set fill color for border layer as clear, because technically it just puts colored layer over your view
borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

//Add border layer as sublayer to your view's main layer
*your view instance*.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

In your case may be the problem with dynamic label's text: if text will be e.g. 900000 it will be drew under border. To solve this you could place you UILAbel inside another view (which will contain shape and border adjustments) and layout it.
Example:
[Structure and constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POzkf.png)

[What i got: container BG - orange, border - white, superview's BG - red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJIrr.png)

Controller's viewDidLoad method code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

        self.label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.label.textAlignment = .center
        self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.label.text = "9000000"

        //Create Border and shape and apply it to container view

        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: containerView.bounds, cornerRadius: containerView.bounds.width / 2).cgPath

        //Set this rounding path to both layers
        shapeLayer.path = path
        borderLayer.path = path

        //adjust border layer
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 20
        borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        //apply shape layer as mask to your view, it will cut your view by the corners
        self.containerView.layer.mask = shapeLayer

        //Set fill color for border layer as clear, because technically it just puts colored layer over your view
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        //Add border layer as sublayer to your view's main layer
        self.containerView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
```

Comment: Well, if you're going the path of using two UIView (`containerView` and `label`), then there is no need for all this, and `layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2; layer.masksToBounds = true` on both views will be enough I guess.

Comment: Yes, true. But, again, this example is only for the case i explaned. If your text will be small and centered, first code example will help to avoid appearance of background colored pixels on border.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to forget about imperfect `borderWidth` altogether and use **two views** inside each other:

```
extension UIView {
    func roundBounds() {
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}

class RoundLabel: UILabel {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        roundBounds()
    }
}

class RoundView: UIView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        roundBounds()
    }
}
```

[image: circular border effect]